# WebView Resize Screen when keypad open

Tags: java, android, webview

i am using a WebView in my Android Apps.I want to show a site which have a EditTest.When i run my apps it's run well but when i click the EditText then my keypad open and my WebView don't resize.
This is my .xml file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".FacebookNewWrapper" >

<!-- Our actual WebView -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/webview_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.facebook.FacebookWebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <!-- Progress bar used to show the loading progress -->

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.Tinfoil.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/webview_top_progress_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- Mostly use for full-screen video playback -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Menu drawer (right) -->

<include layout="@layout/drawer_menu" />
```

I have added

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
 android:launchMode="standard"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

this into my Android Menifest.xml 
and this added into my .java file

```
   getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

but nothing is helpful for me.
How i can solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Delete form your .java file

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Find in your Android Manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

change to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```